# uvcdynctrl is taking 100% CPU

Tags: 14.04, cpu-load

A program `uvcdynctrl` is being spontaneously launched at random times (in an interval of week to month) on my laptop with Ubuntu 14.04. When this happens, the program takes 100% CPU and the temperature sharply rises to almost 100 °C.

Could someone please advise:

- what exactly this program is doing,
- why it takes so much CPU, and
- how to prevent it from random launching?

I could not find much on google, only that is it somehow related to [web camera](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libwebcam/).

Comment: It controls the web cam, as you have found out, and I would be *very* curious to know who or what touches my webcam, it it's not me. I'd be tempted to write a wrapper script around `uvcdynctrl` that logs the use of it to syslog, including the name of the parent process.

Comment: This might be related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libwebcam/+bug/811604) in `libwebcam`.

Comment: @Jos could you please suggest how to write a good wrapper? I have some ideas, but I have never before done anything like this and I would prefer to do it right. Thanks.

Comment: 1. Find out which executable to replace: `which uvcdynctrl`. Let's say this outputs `/usr/bin/uvcdynctrl`. 2. Move that file to (say) `/usr/bin/real-uvcdynctrl`. 3) write a script that outputs the command that *its parent* was called by: `ps -efc | grep $PPID >> /some/log/file`, followed by a call to `real-uvcdynctrl` with the original parameters: `real-uvcdynctrl "$@"`. Save this script as `/usr/bin/uvcdynctrl`. So the next time `uvcdynctrl` is called, the script will write a log entry, then proceed as usual. Bash experts, feel free to improve and correct this sketch of a script.

Comment: I need to add that the `c` flag of `ps` only outputs the full command when `uvcdynctrl` was called with root permissions. Otherwise, you just get the process ID and you need to find out the command yourself, if that is even possible. Also, in this version of the script, you get three lines every time it is called, and you need to find out which of the three is the right one, yourself.